# Unbounded Wildcard Type Parameter vs Abstract Type

Tags: scala

Is anyone able to shed any light on the real differences between these two examples.

```
object ExampleA {
    trait Bar { def n: Int }
    trait Foo[B <: Bar] { def bar: B }

    def getBarIntFromFoo(foo: Foo[_]) =
        getBarInt(foo.bar)

    def getBarInt(bar: Bar) =
        bar.n
}

object ExampleB {
    trait Bar { def n: Int }
    trait Foo {
        type B <: Bar
        def bar: B
    }

    def getBarIntFromFoo(foo: Foo) =
        getBarInt(foo.bar)

    def getBarInt(bar: Bar) =
        bar.n
}
```

I had assumed that the only difference was the way you'd refer to them, but in reality only `ExampleB` compiles and `ExampleA` results in:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error] found   : _$1
[error] required: ExampleA.Bar
[error]      getBarInt(_)
[error]                ^
```

Both `Foo`s have the same type constraints (`B <: Bar`) so I'm a little lost. I imagine I'm simply misunderstanding something pretty basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_` in `Foo[_]` is an existential type. Without any type bounds on it, it will be assumed to be `Any`, even though `Foo[B]` has an upper-bound of `Bar`. This means that `foo.bar` is assumed to be `Any`, instead of a `Bar`. Thus, `getBarInt(foo.bar)` fails, because the compiler thinks you're passing a `Any` instead of a `Bar`.

If you want the parameter to be `Foo[_]`, then it must be bounded here.

```
object ExampleA {
    trait Bar { def n: Int }
    trait Foo[B <: Bar] { def bar: B }

    def getBarIntFromFoo(foo: Foo[_ <: Bar]) =
        getBarInt(foo.bar)

    def getBarInt(bar: Bar) =
        bar.n
}
```

From the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types):

> Scala supports a placeholder syntax for existential types. A wildcard type is of the form `_ >: L <: U`. Both bound clauses may be omitted. If a lower bound clause `>: L` is missing, `>: scala.Nothing` is assumed. **If an upper bound clause `<: U` is missing, `<: scala.Any` is assumed**. A wildcard type is a shorthand for an existentially quantified type variable, where the existential quantification is implicit.

The second example with the type alias just doesn't suffer from this.

Comment: So even though the upper bound is defined on the type, it's still compiled as an `Any` rather than "Any within the bounds defined on the type"?

Answer (score 3):

m-z is correct here. But one question you might ask is, Why does Scala require you to repeat the bound `<: Bar` when it is already required by the definition of `Foo`?

The reason is for consistency with

```
def blah[A](f: Foo[A])
```

Here `[A]` is going to be supplied by the caller, so Foo can't be allowed to apply any extra constraints on it (otherwise the exact definition of blah would be hard to determine). This means that in general, `Foo[x]` can't apply constraints to `X`, even though in some cases it would be safe.

However, there are plans for the future to re-implement existential types as type variables, so perhaps this behavior will change someday.

Comment: I suppose this was the question that was annoying me about it the most. The consistency makes sense. I'll leave m-z as the accepted answer, but thanks for clearing things up!